# Arranging rectangles within a boundary without overlap and x contraints

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, d3.js

I am trying to arrange an unknown number of rectangles so that they dont overlap each other. There are a number of constraints when rearranging rectangles:

- Can ONLY move in the positive y (up) direction with the exception the
  condition where moving up will push the rectangle outside of the
  container boundary.
- CANNOT move in the x (left or right) direction We should get some
  reasonable padding in between rectangles on all sides.
- The top most rectangle should be the first rectangle (denoted by a label in the [jsbin link](http://jsbin.com/itoxef/4))

I wrote a small something that would generate the main problem [here at jsbin](http://jsbin.com/itoxef/4). So far the only thing that comes to my mind is a situation where I iterate through these rectangles back and forth. I was wondering if anyone can suggest an approach or better yet point to an existing solution.

Comment: Have you considered the [treemap layout](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Treemap-Layout)? You should be able to get something fairly close by setting the dimensions correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compute the vertical position of each rectangle using the height of the preceding rectangles. It may be useful to check if the problem has a solution.

```
// Generate random rectangles, with the vertical position set to zero
var padding = 5;
var num_rectangles = 10;
var rectangles = [];
for (var k = 0; k < num_rectangles; k += 1) {
    rectangles.push({ 
        x: 50 * Math.random(),
        y: padding, 
        width: Math.max(50 * Math.random(), 20),
        height: Math.max(50 * Math.random(), 20)
    });
}

// Update the vertical position of the item j as the sum of the heigths 
// of the rectangles 0, ..., j - 1
for (var j = 1; j < num_rectangles; j += 1) {
    rectangles[j].y = rectangles[j - 1].y + rectangles[j - 1].height + padding;
}
```

And then just draw the rectangles as usual. I wrote a small example http://jsfiddle.net/FuepP/2/

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of at the moment is basically a branch and bound search. Starting from the bottom, iteratively resolve colliding pairs by pushing one or the other rectangle up (branching). If you go above the limit, backtrack to the previous branch.

I wouldn't be surprised if solving this problem was NP-Complete. It's a more constrained version of the [bin packing problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem). On the other hand, over-constraining problems tends to make them very easy so maybe it's not NP-Complete. I tried to think of a reduction for a few minutes but didn't come up with anything.